# JQuery filter input

Tags: jquery

`myData` is the JSON response that contains emails. I want to show error in the input fields having the same emails that I get in response.

Following is the code, it works fine on all browsers except Safari and Firefox 8 on MAC OS. Please guide!

```
if (typeof myData.email != "undefined" && myData.email.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.email.length; i++) {
        $('#finalForm :input').filter(function(){ if (this.value == myData.email[i]) { refErr(this); } });
    }
}

function refErr(thisIs) {
        $(thisIs).css('border', '1px solid #E33244');
        $(thisIs).after('<span class="errMsg">Oops! You have already referred this email. Please use a different email.</span>');
    }
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: `$('#finalForm :input').filter(....` is not working on Safari and Firefox 8 on MAC OS. Can you suggest some alternative?